# Recreate contract after any changes to code in Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

I'm using Remix connected to the Geth (Rinkeby) Web3 Provider to write and debug a very basic contract.

Question: After making changes to my contract in the IDE, is compiling sufficient to test the changes, or do I need to deploy a whole new contract for the changes? And if compiling alone is sufficient, how do I update the controls (that allow me to interact with my contract) on the 'Run' tab to reflect the changes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompiling the code will not modify the contracts you already deployed, not even to the JavaScript VM.

Each time you make a change to the code and compile the code again, you have to deploy a new contract.